# Java URLDecoder Декодировать целый объект

Tags: java, объекты, urlencode

Есть к примеру объект

```
{
   field1:"%2B",
   field2:"%2B"
}
```

У него поля закодированы в URL кодировке, как мне перевести их в utf-8. Оригинальный объект имеет гораздо больше полей.
Мне не хочется использовать решение где нужно декодировать все поля по отдельности с помощью  `URLDecode` из `Java`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кроме как пройтись по каждому объекту и применить функцию, можно попробовать привести весь объект к строке и применить для этой строки функцию `URLDecode`, ну и потом распарсить.